Spring Boot 3.x simplest Oauth2 app with github error: [invalid_token_response]
I am new to Spring Boot OAuth2 though I am familiar with Spring Boot. I want my first OAuth2 application to be the simplest possible. I found a tutorial on youtube that seemed to fit my needs:
OAuth2 Login Made Easy in Java: A Spring Boot & Spring Security Walkthrough
The code is at https://github.com/danvega/spring-security-social-login.
I first wanted to use my github account for the login and created an OAuth2 application with Client ID and client secret as instructed.
I put client ID and secret into the application-properties for keys
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.client-id and
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.client-secret, respectively.
On github's application page I put as homepage URL: http://localhost:8080 and as Authorization callback URL I used http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/github
as instructed in the youtube video.
Yet, when I run the app and want to access the secured resource via github I get:

[invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to
retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: I/O error on POST
request for "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token": github.com

It beats me what I am doing wrong. The app is so simple and no comments under the video seem to indicate that anyone had my problem. What am I doing wrong?
I am assuming the problem is with the github app as the Java Spring Boot code is next to trivial.
If needed I'll reprint it here.
In the pom.xml the spring-boot-starter-parent is 3.0.6.
Have I done a simple oversight? How can I fix this?
Update: In my IDE's console I found this error:

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: github.com

That's strange. I can access github.com in my browser no problem.

I cloned https://github.com/danvega/spring-security-social-login, switched my existing GitHub OAuth to the settings in your question, ran the appllication, and it worked as expected. BR
